# Unable to convert strings to proper integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to convert a string to an integer in javascript and then comparing it to an integer variable I created. I have read many many things online but nothing worked so far. This is my code:

`var followedUsers = $('.ProfileNav-item.ProfileNav-item--following.is-active').find('.ProfileNav-value').html();`

so when I type followedUsers in console I get "1256". I tried parseInt as follows:

```
var x = parseInt(followedUsers,10);
```

But when I type x in console I get 2. Yes it is an integer but its not correct integer.
I also tried parseFloat. It gives the same result. This one didn't work either.

```
var x=parseInt(followedUsers.valueOf(),10);
```

I dont know if this is a thing but I was just messing around trying different things. I saw another guy's question. So I gave that a shot:

```
var x = +followedUsers
```

This one gave me a NaN.

```
var x = followedUsers*1
```

This one also gave me a NaN.

I tried converting my integer value to a string and comparing them that way but that doesn't gives me correct outputs. I am running out of ideas guys, am I missing something here? Changing a string to an integer shouldn't be this hard, right?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem? Otherwise it's tough for us to narrow down where the problem lies. (Since `console.log(parseInt("1256",10))` seems to work just fine.)

Comment: Have you tried just `var x = +"1256";`? Perhaps `followedUsers` isn't what you think it is. All the methods you've posted are working with just `"1256"`.

Comment: I stay away from jQuery as much as I can (for good reason, obviously), but I suspect that `html()` returns something which isn't actually a string. Could you try `typeof followedUsers` and `+followedUsers.toString()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the old browser in my university computer lab doesn't support parseInt or any other methods I mentioned above. It worked fine when I tried it on other computers. Although I believe this post will be useful for anybody looking for conversion in means of seeing all the methods in one place

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `followedUsers` isn't what you think it is.

I made a simple example in JSBin, trying to simulate you problem and everything is working:

http://jsbin.com/huzegovaxa/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Try getting followedUsers with .val() insted of .html()

Comment: I cant get the value of the tag with .val()

Answer (score -1):

Try

`var x = parseInt(followedUsers);`

Comment: This is equivalent to what OP tried with `parseInt(followedUsers, 10)`. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: ... except it won't assume base 10.

Comment: Except it does in this case... From my source link: If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following: ... If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

Comment: I didn't write it because that was the first thing I tried, its no good. Thanks tough